# compression with btrfs-send / btrfs-receive

Tags: btrfs, compression

When I send a compressed subvol (i.e., one part of a filesystem mounted with the `compress` mount option) with `btrfs-send`, does `btrfs-send` send it compressed, or does it decompress it first?

Similarly, when I receive the subvol with `btrfs-receive`, does `btrfs-receive` re-compress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `--compressed-data` send data that is compressed on the filesystem directly without decompressing it
>
> If the receiver supports the BTRFS_IOC_ENCODED_WRITE ioctl (added in Linux 6.0), it can also write it directly without decompressing it. Otherwise, the receiver will fall back to decompressing it and writing it normally.
>
> This requires protocol version 2 or higher. If --proto was not used, then --compressed-data implies --proto 2.

https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-send.html

Comment: Nice to know they added that since.

Answer (score 6):

`btrfs-send` will perform `read` syscalls, which means it will decompress the data indeed. Then data are streamed uncompressed, and `btrfs-receive` will perform `write` syscalls, which will compress depending on the target `btrfs` system `compress` mount option.

So for instance, you could have an existing `btrfs` system with all kinds of compression used for different files, and write to a new one where all data will be `zstd`-compressed.